# batch script to save directory of running process in windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Is there a way to save the directory of running process to a variable? say i want to save the full path of mysqld.exe which is **c:\program files\mysql\mysql server 5.6\bin**, this batch script should search for a process directory and save it without **\processName.exe** , is it doable?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for

```
set "MYSQLDIR=c:\program files\mysql\mysql server 5.6\bin"
```

**update:** It's a bit a bit finicky, and you'll need to use powershell to get the path, but this seems to work for me:

```
@echo off

set "tmpname=%TMP%\fproc%RANDOM%"
powershell get-process ^| format-list path | findstr %1 > %TMPNAME%
set /p T1=<%TMPNAME%
call :get_path result "%T1:~7%"
echo %result%

goto:cleanup

:get_path
    set "%~1=%~dp2"
    exit /b

:cleanup
    del %TMPNAME%
```

save it to a file named `procpath.bat` and pass the process name:

```
c:\srv\tmp> procpath pycharm64
C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.3.2\bin\
```

Comment: no sir this doesn't meet my request, i want the batch to auto search through process running for a given process and give me the working directory of this process without \processName.exe

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: set name of executable to locate.
:: This one onmy system - adjust to suit
SET "targetname=boinc.exe"
CALL :zapvars
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a IN ('wmic process list full') DO IF "%%b" neq "" (
 IF "%%a"=="CommandLine" CALL :report
 SET "$%%a=%%b"
)
CALL :report

GOTO :EOF

:report
IF NOT DEFINED $processid GOTO zapvars
IF NOT DEFINED $executablepath GOTO zapvars
:: select your target executablename here
SET $executablepath|FINDSTR /i /L /e /c:"\\%targetname%" >NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO zapvars

FOR %%z IN ("%$executablepath%") DO SET "pathwithslosh=%%~dpz
ECHO PATH without \executablename = "%pathwithslosh:~0,-1%"
:zapvars
FOR %%z IN (
CommandLine CSName Description ExecutablePath ExecutionState
Handle HandleCount InstallDate KernelModeTime MaximumWorkingSetSize
MinimumWorkingSetSize Name OSName OtherOperationCount
OtherTransferCount PageFaults PageFileUsage ParentProcessId
PeakPageFileUsage PeakVirtualSize PeakWorkingSetSize
Priority PrivatePageCount ProcessId QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage
QuotaPagedPoolUsage QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage 
QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage ReadOperationCount ReadTransferCount
SessionId Status TerminationDate ThreadCount UserModeTime
VirtualSize WindowsVersion WorkingSetSize WriteOperationCount 
WriteTransferCount
) DO SET "$%%z="
GOTO :eof
```

Using `wmic` and parsing - can get many parts of the process characteristics